# Removing punctuation in lists in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, punctuation

Creating a Python program that converts the string to a list, uses a loop to remove any punctuation and then converts the list back into a string and prints the sentence without punctuation.

```
punctuation=['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]

str=input("Type in a line of text: ")

alist=[]
alist.extend(str)
print(alist)

#Use loop to remove any punctuation (that appears on the punctuation list) from the list

print(''.join(alist))
```

This is what I have so far. I tried using something like: `alist.remove(punctuation)` but I get an error saying something like `list.remove(x): x not in list`. I didn't read the question properly at first and realized that I needed to do this by using a loop so I added that in as a comment and now I'm stuck. I was, however, successful in converting it from a list back into a string.

Comment: Just use `replace` or `strip`.

Answer (score 5):

```
import string
punct = set(string.punctuation)

''.join(x for x in 'a man, a plan, a canal' if x not in punct)
Out[7]: 'a man a plan a canal'
```

Explanation: `string.punctuation` is pre-defined as:

```
'!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~'
```

The rest is a straightforward comprehension.  A `set` is used to speed up the filtering step.

Comment: I'd pull the `set` out of the genexp; otherwise you're building it for each `x`.

Comment: Just to understand, what does it mean `pull the set out of the genexp` ? Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: @Kyrol see [the set() trap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap).

Comment: Thank you. I'm programming in Python since few weeks. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I found a easy way to do it:

```
punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]
str = raw_input("Type in a line of text: ")

for i in punctuation:
  str = str.replace(i,"")

print str
```

With this way you will not get any error.

Comment: It iterates over the list many times which could be annoying for very large inputs, but nice. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
punctuation=['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]
result = ""
for character in str:
   if(character not in punctuation):
       result += character
print result
```

Comment: Try using `replace` or `strip`

Comment: I assumed it was for a class where they had to use a loop based on the question

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer of how to tokenize the given statements by using python. the python version I used is 3.4.4
Assume that I have text which is saved as one.txt. then I have saved my python program in the directory where my file is (i.e. one.txt). The following is my python program:

with open('one.txt','r')as myFile:
    str1=myFile.read()
    print(str1)# This is to print the given statements with punctuations(before removal of punctuations)
   # The following is the list of punctuations that we need to remove, add any more if I forget
    punctuation = ['(', ')', '?', ':', ';', ',', '.', '!', '/', '"', "'"]
for i in punctuation:
        str1 = str1.replace(i," ") #to make empty the place where punctuation is there.
        myList=[]
        myList.extend(str1.split(" "))
print (str1) #this is to print the given statements without puctions(after Removal of punctuations)
for i in myList:
   # print ("____________")
    print(i,end='\n')
    print ("____________")

==============next I will post for you how to remove stop words============
until that let you comment if it is useful.
Thank you