# list comprehension filtering - "the set() trap"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

A reasonably common operation is to filter one `list` based on another `list`.  People quickly find that this:

```
[x for x in list_1 if x in list_2]
```

is slow for large inputs - it's O(n*m).  Yuck.  How do we speed this up?  Use a `set` to make filtering lookups O(1):

```
s = set(list_2)
[x for x in list_1 if x in s]
```

This gives nice overall O(n) behavior.  I however often see even veteran coders fall into *The Trap*™:

```
[x for x in list_1 if x in set(list_2)]
```

Ack!  This is again O(n*m) since python builds `set(list_2)` *every* time, not just once.

---

I thought that was the end of the story - python can't optimize it away to only build the `set` once.  Just be aware of the pitfall.  Gotta live with it.  Hmm.

```
#python 3.3.2+
list_2 = list(range(20)) #small for demonstration purposes
s = set(list_2)
list_1 = list(range(100000))
def f():
    return [x for x in list_1 if x in s]
def g():
    return [x for x in list_1 if x in set(list_2)]
def h():
    return [x for x in list_1 if x in {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19}]

%timeit f()
100 loops, best of 3: 7.31 ms per loop

%timeit g()
10 loops, best of 3: 77.4 ms per loop

%timeit h()
100 loops, best of 3: 6.66 ms per loop
```

Huh, python (3.3) *can* optimize away a set literal.  It's even faster than `f()` in this case, presumably because it gets to replace a `LOAD_GLOBAL` with a `LOAD_FAST`.

```
#python 2.7.5+
%timeit h()
10 loops, best of 3: 72.5 ms per loop
```

Python 2 notably doesn't do this optimization.  I've tried investigating further what python3 is doing but unfortunately `dis.dis` cannot probe the innards of comprehension expressions.  Basically everything interesting turns into `MAKE_FUNCTION`.

So now I'm wondering - why can python 3.x optimize away the set literal to only build once, but not `set(list_2)`?

Comment: Thank you for calling my attention to this detail.

Comment: `f` appears to be a little bit faster if you use a frozenset instead of a set.

Comment: This comes a bit late, but in case you haven't figured it out in the meantime: You can use `dis.dis` on the inner code object as well, you just have to dig the code object out of the outer code object's co_consts. Eg. `f = lambda: {a for b in c}; dis.dis(f.func_code.co_consts[1])`

Comment: FYI, the set literal optimization was introduced as a result of this bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue6690 , resolved in the Py3 development period, but not backported.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

In order to optimize `set(list_2)`, the interpreter needs to prove that `list_2` (and all of its elements) does not change between iterations. This is a hard problem in the general case, and it would not surprise me if the interpreter does not even attempt to tackle it.

On the other hand a set literal cannot change its value between iterations, so the optimization is known to be safe.

Comment: It strikes me that this makes the case for introducing a `where` clause to comprehension syntax, such that variables can be declared in the expression.

Comment: Indeed, you can make a pathological `list_2` that changes during the comprehension.

Comment: Yet the interpreter doesn't even optimize `set([0,1,2,...,19])` — that runs just as slowly as `set(list_2)`.

Comment: Ahh, the interpreter also needs to prove that the `set` fn does not change between iterations. That's why it doesn't optimize `set([0,1,2,...,19])`.

Answer (score 39):

From [What’s New In Python 3.2](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/3.2.html#optimizations):

> Python’s peephole optimizer now recognizes patterns such `x in {1, 2,
>   3}` as being a test for membership in a set of constants. The optimizer
>   recasts the set as a frozenset and stores the pre-built constant.

Comment: Presumably it's transitive as well, recognizing earlier that `list2` is a constant range of integers, and so `set(list2)` can also be replaced.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question: "why can python 3.x optimize away the set literal to only build once, but not `set(list_2)`?" The quote doesn't answer why the same optimization cannot be done for `set(list_2)`.

Comment: @chepner: Unfortunately from the timing results for the `g()` function in the OP's question, it seems your presumption is incorrect.

Comment: Oh, I didn't read far enough into the question; I though `set(list2)` was being optimized.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I think it does answer the question because the quote says the optimizer recognizes a set literal literal, nothing more.

Comment: @martineau Yes, but *why* doesn't it recognize nothing more? I mean: it's like saying "python optimizes set literals and not other things because it optimizes only set literals". He only confirmed that the OP was correct in his deduction that other cases are not optimized. The why isn't hard: because a set literal is a *compile time* constant, while a call to `set` isn't, and the interpreter doesn't have much time to optimize at runtime. This is *not* mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @Bakuriu: Guess I just consider the omission of all that OK because it's obvious.

Comment: @Bakuriu You can edit the answer to include that explanation.

Comment: The compiler can never optimize `set(x)` because it can't know what the name `set` will be bound to until runtime.

Comment: @asmeurer: That's a good point, but I'm not sure if I'd use the word "never" here. The compiler could compile both versions (a version for when `set` is such-and-such type, and a version for when it's anything else), together with a branch that selects the appropriate version at runtime. Given how common and basic `set` is, and given that it's predefined, this approach might even be worth it.

Comment: Another issue: computing the set of an object can in general have side-effects. The object could be an iterator that runs out. And objects' `__hash__` could do anything. I think the example here only works because it's a set of literals.

Answer (score 18):

> So now I'm wondering - why can python 3.x optimize away the set
>   literal to only build once, but not set(list_2)?

No one's mentioned this issue yet: how do you know `set([1,2,3])` and `{1, 2, 3}` are the same thing?

```
>>> import random
>>> def set(arg):
...     return [random.choice(range(5))]
... 
>>> list1 = list(range(5))
>>> [x for x in list1 if x in set(list1)]
[0, 4]
>>> [x for x in list1 if x in set(list1)]
[0]
```

You can't shadow a literal; you can shadow `set`.  So before you can consider hoisting, you need to know not just that `list1` isn't being affected, you need to be sure that `set` is what you think it is.  Sometimes you can do that, either under restrictive conditions at compile time or more conveniently at runtime, but it's definitely nontrivial.

It's kind of funny: often when the suggestion of doing optimizations like this comes up, one pushback is that as nice as they are, it makes it harder to reason about what Python performance is going to be like, even algorithmically.  Your question provides some evidence for this objection.

Comment: Basically, each mutable object would need a counter in it that is incremented whenever the object is modified. Then `set(mylist)` could be memoized where `mylist` has the same counter value as it did when the `set` was constructed, i.e., it has not been modified. This would add overhead to a ton of operations (every item or attribute assignment) for functionality that simply wouldn't be useful very often.

Answer (score 13):

*Too long for a comment*

This won't speak to the optimization details or v2 vs. v3 differences. But when I encounter this in some situations, I find making a context manager out of the data object is useful:

```
class context_set(set):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        pass

def context_version():
    with context_set(list_2) as s:
        return [x for x in list_1 if x in s]
```

Using this I see:

```
In [180]: %timeit context_version()
100 loops, best of 3: 17.8 ms per loop
```

and in some cases, it provides a nice stop-gap between creating the object before the comprehension vs. creating it within the comprehension, and allows custom tear-down code if you want it.

A more generic version can be made using `contextlib.contextmanager`. Here's a quick-and-dirty version of what I mean.

```
def context(some_type):
    from contextlib import contextmanager
    generator_apply_type = lambda x: (some_type(y) for y in (x,))
    return contextmanager(generator_apply_type)
```

Then one can do:

```
with context(set)(list_2) as s:
    # ...
```

or just as easily

```
with context(tuple)(list_2) as t:
    # ...
```

Answer (score 10):

The basic reason is that a literal really can't change, whereas if it's an expression like `set(list_2)`, it's possible that evaluating the target expression or the iterable of the comprehension could change the value of `set(list_2)`.  For instance, if you have

```
[f(x) for x in list_1 if x in set(list_2)]
```

It is possible that `f` modifies `list_2`.

Even for a simple `[x for x in blah ...]` expression, it's theoretically possible that the `__iter__` method of `blah` could modify `list_2`.

I would imagine there is some scope for optimizations, but the current behavior keeps things simpler.  If you start adding optimizations for things like "it is only evaluated once if the target expression is a single bare name and the iterable is a builtin list or dict..." you make it much more complicated to figure out what will happen in any given situation.