# Python calculator concatenates instead of preforming operations

Tags: python, class, calculator

I'm new to Python and I'm attempting to program a calculator. The problem is I can't find a way to make the variables `num1` and `num2` do the operation I have listed for them. All they do is concatenate the two numbers instead of performing the operation, any suggestions? Thanks.

```
letter = ()

class Calc():

     print raw_input("What operation do you want to do?\n\tA) Addition\n\tB) Subtraction\n\ ")
     num1 = raw_input("Please enter your first number: ")
     num2 = raw_input("Please enter your second number: ")

     if letter == 'A' or 'a':
        print "The sum of", num1, "plus", num2, "equals"
        print num1 + num2
     elif letter == 'B' or 'b':
        print "The difference of", num1, "minus", num2, "equals"
        print num1 - num2
```

Comment: Two bugs. First, you don't parse the strings into ints or floats, so Python interprets `+` as string concatenation. Second, `letter == 'A' or 'a'` doesn't mean "if letter is one of those things". It means `(letter == 'A') or 'a'`, which is always true because `'a'` is true in a boolean context.

Answer (score 4):

[`raw_input`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) returns a string, so your two inputs are concatenated. You need to convert that input to a number before using it with numeric operators.

```
num1 = int(raw_input("Please enter your first number: "))
```

You can use either [`float`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) or [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) to convert the input string to a number.

You also need to change

```
if letter == 'A' or 'a':
```

to

```
if letter == 'A' or letter == 'a':
```

Comment: Would it be more Pythonic to say `if letter in ['A','a']:`?

Comment: @darthbith a set literal is better than a list literal, but almost certainly best to say `if letter.lower() == 'a'`

Comment: @darthbith That probably is a bit more Pythonic. As roippi points out, there are also lower() and upper() functions that could be used in this case.

Comment: @roippi so it should be `if letter in {'A','a'}:`? Why is that better than a list? A link to further reading is fine too, I couldn't find anything in my quick googling :-) Thanks! And yes, the `lower()` or `upper()` function is much easier to parse!

Comment: @darthbith the whole answer is a little too long to fit into a comment box. Basically a set literal is a declaration of *constants* - `in` lookups are constant time as opposed to linear time, and the compiler can do more compile-time magic.  That's the practical side of it.  Less-practically, that's just what sets are for - membership tests when you don't care about order.  They're the tool for the job.

Comment: I think for a two element set or list the lookup time doesn't matter.  Especially because this isn't in a loop.  Isn't this discussion just a case of premature optimization?

Comment: @roippi Thanks. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap) of yours has some good details too, although it isn't directly about this issue.

Comment: @SethMMorton In this case, yes. Its good to have good habits though :-)

Answer (score 2):

You are using 
raw_input()
which converts the input to strings.

If you want to add them together, you would like to use 
num1 = float(num1)

before adding.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are doing string operations. `raw_input` returns a `string`, so you must manually convert it to an `int` or `float` using: `float()` or `int()`.

Do this:

`print int(num1) + int(num2)` in order to print the numbers in their addition form.

Answer (score -1):

I think this will do what you ask:

```
letter = raw_input("What operation do you want to do?\n\tA) 
         Addition\n\tB)Subtraction\n")
num1 = input("Please enter your first number: ")
num2 = input("Please enter your second number: ")
if letter == 'A' or 'a':
   print "The sum of", num1, "plus", num2, "equals"
   print num1 + num2
elif letter == 'B' or 'b':
   print "The difference of", num1, "minus", num2, "equals"
   print num1 - num2
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the "or" issue (the OP never noticed that `str - str` will fail because of it), and advising someone to use the more dangerous `input` over `raw_input` is probably not the best choice.