# Generate inverse sequence

Tags: python, range

I have a sequence

```
range(0,50,3)

[0, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48]
```

This is the sequence I want to generate (excluding the 3rd element each time), but being able to start and end at nth number:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, ...]
```

Comment: can you give a more complete example of what you want? what you mean by inverse?

Comment: its the sequence I want to generate, i.e. excluding every 3rd element (`range(0,50,1)-(range(0,50,3)`), let me do an edit

Comment: Do you need an inverse of a range-like  sequence or of an arbitrary integer sequence?

Comment: It's more a complement than an inverse IMO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
def inv_range(start, stop, step):
  for val in range(start, stop):
    if (val - start) % step != 0:
      yield val

print list(inv_range(0,50,3))
```

This prints

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, ...
```

P.S. If you're using Python 2, replace `range()` with `xrange()` to get a constant-memory solution.

Answer (score 2):

Build a `set` of the numbers you want to *exclude*, and test for that in a list comprehension for the full range:

```
>>> checkset = set(range(0, 50, 3))
>>> [x for x in range(50) if x not in checkset]
[1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 10, 11, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 22, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 41, 43, 44, 46, 47, 49]
```

Converting the list to a set is not critical, but makes for faster lookup when all you're doing is comparing

Comment: build the set outside of the comprehension, you're building it each time the `if` statement is evaluated.

Comment: learned that one [the hard way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap) :-)

Answer (score 2):

For this particular case :

```
[x for x in range(50) if x % 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most efficient solution, but quick and easy to understand

```
excludes = range(0,50,3)
others = [x for x in range(50) if x not in excludes]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
r = range(0,50)
del r[::3]
print r
# [1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, ...]
```

Answer (score 0):

For questions like these, where someone is asking "How can I slightly modify the behaviour of a Python built-in function to do X?" I would suggest looking at the PyPy implementation of said function and then just modify it.

In this case, here are PyPy's [range() and xrange() implementations](https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/src/b28540754b6b4410462f172935cf279b05d09c0a/pypy/module/__builtin__/app_functional.py).

I realize it's not the easy way out, but you might learn something new in the process.

Basically it looks like what you want is a variant of `range()` that returns the values which are usually skipped (i.e., the complement of `range()`). Using `range()`'s implementation as a starting point, it doesn't look like it would take much work.