# Filter Dictionary According to Existing List

Tags: python, list, dictionary, genetics

Still a Python novice so please go easy on me...

I've got a dictionary set up:

```
new_dict
```

I'd like to filter to return the keys, where any of the values attached to each key match the value in an existing list I have set up:

```
list(data.Mapped_gene)
```

Any ideas?

Edit: 
I still haven't been able to make this work.

The csv tables and keys are all strings if that helps.

Here is the full code to broaden understanding:

```
import csv    
new_dict = {}
with open(raw_input("Enter csv file (including path)"), 'rb') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for row in reader:
    if row[0] in new_dict:
      new_dict[row[0]].append(row[1:])
    else:
      new_dict[row[0]] = row[1:]
print new_dict

#modified from: http://bit.ly/1iOS7Gu
import pandas
colnames = ['Date Added to Catalog',    'PUBMEDID', 'First Author', 'Date',     'Journal',  'Link', 'Study',    'DT',   'Initial Sample Size',  'Replication Sample Size',  'Region',   'Chr_id',   'Chr_pos',  'Reported Gene(s)', 'Mapped_gene',  'p-Value',  'Pvalue_mlog',  'p-Value (text)',   'OR or beta',   '95% CI (text)',    'Platform [SNPs passing QC]',   'CNV']
data = pandas.read_csv('C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\gwascatalog.csv', names=colnames)


my_list = list(data.Mapped_gene)
my_set = set(my_list)

[k for k, v in new_dict.items() if any(x in my_set for x in v)]
```

Error Message:
"TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'"

Comment: The values are stored in list/tuple?

Answer (score 3):

Use `any` and a list comprehension:

```
my_list = list(data.Mapped_gene)
keys = [k for k, v in new_dict.items() if any(x in my_list for x in v)]
```

In case `my_list` is huge then convert it to a `set` first as it provides `O(1)` lookup.

Comment: This looks great. How do I get the output?

Comment: @user3297046 See the updated answer. Store the return value of list comprehension in a variable.

Comment: Still couldn't make it quite work. See edited question, above.

Comment: @user3297046 Looks like you've a list of lists, try using: `my_set = set(y for x in my_list for y in x)`

Answer (score 2):

```
geneset = set(data.Mapped_gene)
[k for k, v in new_dict.items() if geneset.intersection(v)]
```

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary I thought the compiler optimises this.  But maybe it can't, since the name "set" can be rebound

Comment: [list comprehension filtering - “the set() trap”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap)

Answer (score 0):

To increase the performance of the lookup transform the list to a set.

```
gene_set = set(data.Mapped_gene)
```

Then use a list comprehension like shown in the other examples or a dictionary comprehension
if you are interested in the value as well.

```
{k:v for k, v in my_dict.iteritems() if v in gene_set}
```

The method `iteritems()` method on `my_dict` is especially useful if `my_dict` is huge. In order to make your method more memory efficient you can use a generator instead of a list or dictionary comprehension:

```
(k for k, v in my_dict.iteritems() if v in gene_set)
```