# How to find the max number(s) in a list with tied numbers

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing, max

So say I have a list like:

```
my_list = [12, 13, 51, 21, 22, 58, 45.1, 34.2, 56, 6, 58, 58]
```

So the max number in this is obviously 58, but I don't just want to return *one* 58, I want a list of all the indexes that have that max number.

Basically for this I want the result `[5, 10, 11]`

I know that if I want the max number I can do `my_list.index(max(my_list))` but that will simply give me the first index.

Any tips? Also, I want to stick to simple methods such as `sort`, `max`, `len`, etc...

Comment: See also [`more_itertools.locate()`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.locate)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all positions of the maximum value in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3989016/how-to-find-all-positions-of-the-maximum-value-in-a-list)

Answer (score 24):

You can determine the `maxval` with [`max`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max):

```
maxval = max(my_list)
```

Then get the indices using [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) and a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
indices = [index for index, val in enumerate(my_list) if val == maxval]
```

For your example, I get

```
maxval == 58
indices = [5, 10, 11]
```

---

As per Keyser's suggestion, you could save iterating over the list twice (once to determine `maxval`, once to find matching `index`es) by doing:

```
maxval = None
for index, val in enumerate(my_list):
    if maxval is None or val > maxval:
        indices = [index]
        maxval = val
    elif val == maxval:
        indices.append(index)
```

Comment: Or, to replace runtime with some memory, traverse the list once and keep track of the indices of the biggest so far, somehow. I don't have anything pythonic.

Comment: Nice one. Definitely +1

Comment: Slight but important error in your second example: it needs to append `index` to `indices`, not `val`...  Also, I don't think all the overhead makes it worth saving that extra iteration. For a short list, the list comprehension version is twice as fast as the `elif` method, and for a longer list it was 4x faster.

Comment: it is failing if the list has negative values in it..@jonrsharpe

Comment: @Achy97 as far as I can tell it works fine with negative values. For example if I run with `my_list = [12, 13, 51, 21, -22, 58, 45.1, 34.2, -56, 6, 58, 58]` I still get `[5, 10, 11]`. It's unclear what your specific problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to enumerate and list comprehension, you can also use filter:

```
maxval = max(my_list)
indices = list(filter(lambda x: my_list[x]==maxval, list(range(len(my_list)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to do the most Pythonic way as possible

```
my_list = [12, 13, 51, 21, 22, 58, 45.1, 34.2, 56, 6, 58, 58] 
max_indices = [i for i in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[i] == max(my_list)]
```

---

Edit:
Ashwini is right. max() needs to be outside the list, so...

```
max_value = max(my_list)
max_indices = [i for i in range(len(my_list)) if my_list[i] == max_value]
```

Comment: I think enumerate is more pythonic than indices. But it might not be

Comment: Is it O(N^2) because max() is inside the list?

Comment: Yes: each call to `max()` is `O(n)`, and you do it `n` times.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary and jonrsharpe, is python that stupid? :p Not that we should assume it's that smart, I'm just asking.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ We can easily hide `max` with any `max` function we want, so Python cannot optimize this stuff.

Comment: @ᴋᴇʏsᴇʀ [list comprehension filtering - “the set() trap”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap)

Answer (score -1):

Enumerate will help you to get the value and location

```
maxx = max(my_list)
for i,j in enumerate(my_list):
    if j == maxx:
        print i,j
```

output

5 58

10 58

11 58