# How can I return the index of maximum value of a list if there is two maximum values existed

Tags: python

I used the following function to return the maximum value index is the list:

```
def explicit(l):
'''This function returns the index of the largest item in the list'''
max_val = max(l)
max_idx = l.index(max_val)
return max_idx
```

However, the function seems not working if there are two maximum values.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: What doesn't work about it? And what do you want it to do if there is more than one maximum value? Return all the indices?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find the max number(s) in a list with tied numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861730/how-to-find-the-max-numbers-in-a-list-with-tied-numbers)

Comment: Actually, the well-spotted dupe has it.