# Removing a row in a DataFrame when a or b or c is true

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe df that has five columns. The first column is named Phase and contains text. I would like to eliminate any rows in the dataframe where Phase is either 'xyz' or 'ab' or 'tlimit'

I tried the following but it didn't work:

```
df=df[df.Phase != 'xyz' or 'ab' or 'tlimit']
```

I also tried:

```
df=df[df.Phase != 'xyz' or df.Phase!='ab' or df.Pase !='tlimit']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df = df[~df.Phase.isin(['xyz', 'ab', 'tlimit'])]`

Comment: A set would be better than a list.

Comment: If it has three elements it is silly to care about the difference. If the set of items to exclude will be variable, then the OP can write this into a helper function that uses e.g. [my context manager recipe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap/20057101#20057101) to work with it as a set for the duration of the context where that matters. But that extra work isn't part of *this* question.

Comment: @Emre actually the first thing that isin does is make it into a set, but that's more an implementation detail (in future it is likely to be a more low level object).

Comment: is that a minus sign or a tilda? When I do this I use minus sign. Is it the same?

Comment: It's a tilde, for logical negation of each element in an array.