# Compiler optimization of operations on constants

Tags: python, optimization, compilation

The 0th loop below runs much faster* than the 1st (3× for Python-2.7,  5× for Python-3.4):

```
for x in range(0,999999):
    "u" in {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}
```

```
for x in range(0,999999):
    "u" in set("aeiou")
```

It seems that Python, when given `{"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}`, builds the set once, but when given `set("aeiou")`, builds the set every time it's needed.

Is this correct? If so, why does Python not optimize the latter?

---

* *As measured using `time python -c '<code>'`*

Comment: Related: [list comprehension filtering - “the set() trap”](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20056458/list-comprehension-filtering-the-set-trap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python interpreter doesn't recognize `set("aeiou")` as a constant because although it's trivial to tell that `"aeiou"` won't change, it's much harder to tell whether or not the `set` function will change.

The interpreter *could* check that `set()` is not reassigned anywhere within the loop, but I guess the hassle is just not worth it.

Comment: Why would Python recognize a function call as a constant? A user can assign the `set` variable to anything and that's not the case with literals. As stated in my answer in other post this optimization was added in Python 3.2: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20056585/846892

Comment: @Ashwini: Ahhh. I see now. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling a constructor in every loop.  Try again:

```
import time

start = time.time()
for x in range(0,999999):
    "u" in {"a", "e", "i", "o", "u"}
print time.time() - start, "for dictionary look-up"

start = time.time()
for x in range(0,999999):
    "u" in ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u"]
print time.time() - start, "for list look-up"    start = time.time()

for x in range(0,999999):
    "u" in set("aeiou")
print time.time() - start, "for set construction"

start = time.time()
vowel = set("aeiou")
for x in range(0,999999):
    "u" in vowel
print time.time() - start, "for set reference"
```

This gives the times:

```
0.292190074921 for dictionary look-up
0.160042047501 for list look-up
0.529402971268 for set construction
0.098151922226 for set reference
```

Answer (score 1):

I created functions f1 and f2 based on your snippets (from #0 and #1 respectively). Then I use the dis module. Long story short is you can see that the set constructor is being called in the second case within the loop (31 in the second dis). Whereas a constant is just loaded in the first (25 in the first dis).

```
In [20]: dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              33 (to 36)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (999999)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                16 (to 35)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          22 LOAD_CONST               3 ('u')
             25 LOAD_CONST               8 (frozenset({'e', 'o', 'a', 'u', 'i'}))
             28 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             31 POP_TOP
             32 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   35 POP_BLOCK
        >>   36 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             39 RETURN_VALUE

In [21]: dis.dis(f2)
  2           0 SETUP_LOOP              39 (to 42)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (0)
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 (999999)
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            2 (2 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                22 (to 41)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  3          22 LOAD_CONST               3 ('u')
             25 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (set)
             28 LOAD_CONST               4 ('aeiou')
             31 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             34 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             37 POP_TOP
             38 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   41 POP_BLOCK
        >>   42 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             45 RETURN_VALUE
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case you're creating the set once at compile time (when the the python code is compiled to python byte-ops). In the second you're creating the set once for every iteration of the loop.